# MongoDB Query Embedded Document Field

Tags: mongodb

My collection structure is like in the picture below:

[image]

I'm trying to query the field "name" inside every engine:

```
db.getCollection('scan').find({},
   {
        "engines": {
            "$elemMatch": {
                "name": 1
            }
        }
    }
)
```

but the returning results contain only the "_id":

[image]

Does anyone know why?
Thanks!

Comment: In addition, screen captures are usually considered bad style here as they do not permit someone to copy-paste your test case in order to [reproduce your issue](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SylvainLeroux It's not a typo. can you tell me how to tun the query correctly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I'm trying to query the field "name" inside every engine:

Assuming this data sample:

```
db.collection.insert([
  { engines: { ahnlab: { name: "x", value: "1" }}},
  { engines: { ahnlab: { name: "y", value: "2" }}},
])
```

You can query all embedded fields `name` using the dot-notation in the projection operator:

```
> db.collection.find({},{"engines.ahnlab.name": 1, "_id":0 })
{ "engines" : { "ahnlab" : { "name" : "x" } } }
{ "engines" : { "ahnlab" : { "name" : "y" } } }
```

- `"engines.ahnlab.name": 1` will instruct MongoDB to keep (`1`) the embedded name field;
- `"_id": 0` will instruct MongoDB to *not* keep the `_id` field.

---

If you need your output as a flat data structure, you should use the aggregation framework and the [`$project` operator](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) to rewrite your documents:

```
> db.collection.aggregate([
    {$project: { name: "$engines.ahnlab.name", _id: 0 }}
])
{ "name" : "x" }
{ "name" : "y" }
```