# Mongo embedded document field query

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have an existing collection with documents similar to below

```
{
    "_id" : UUID("ef2f3778-c74a-4a40-9169-a7798bc6c776"),
    "feedId" : UUID("677d0a5a-0ceb-43d9-954d-bfefddc22ca2"),
    "events" : {
        "1500" : {
            "t" : ISODate("2020-08-20T02:25:00.000Z"),
            "a" : {
                "Manager" : "Joe",
                "Amount" : 20.3
            }
        },
        "1800" : {
            "t" : ISODate("2020-08-20T02:30:00.000Z"),
            "a" : {
                "Manager" : "Joe",
                "Amount" : 21.3
            }
        },
        "2100" : {
            "t" : ISODate("2020-08-20T02:35:00.000Z"),
            "a" : {
                "Manager" : "Joe",
                "Amount" : 22.3
            }
        },
        "2400" : {
            "t" : ISODate("2020-08-20T02:40:00.000Z"),
            "a" : {
                "Manager" : "Joe",
                "Amount" : 23.3
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I am interested in a query that returns all the Amount field values ordered in time (the "t" field).  Now, I recognize the "events" embedded document is not structured properly most likely. It should be an array.  But this is the hand dealt I am afraid, i.e. don't have an option to change the documents.  How do I get a query that returns something akin to [20.3, 21.3, 22.3, 23.3, etc.] from all the objects in the collection with the same feedId?

Edit: I'll add that the event objects/documents don't have a uniform name across each collection object.  I.e. here you see 1500, 1800, 2100, etc. this document but the next document may have 1500, and 3000 only.

Reference to another post who had the same question but hit a wall it seems (without changing the document schema to arrays):

[MongoDB Query Embedded Document Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31178624/mongodb-query-embedded-document-field)

Comment: Can you post the expected output please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@J.F's answer got me close. Here is the query that worked for me:

```
db.collection.aggregate(
    [
        { $match: { feedId: 2 } },
        { $project: { events: {$objectToArray: "$events"} } },
        {
            "$unwind": "$events"
        },
        {
            "$sort": {
              "events.v.t": 1
            }
        },
        { $group: {  "_id": null, Amounts: { $push: "$events.v.a.Amount" } } },
        {
          "$project": {
            "Amounts": 1,
            "_id": 0
        }
      }
    ]
)
```

It's producing the expected result for me. I hope it's correct.

Result:

```
/* 1 */
{
    "Amounts" : [ 
        20.3, 
        21.3, 
        22.3, 
        23.3, 
        24.3, 
        25.3, 
        26.3, 
        27.3, 
        28.3, 
        29.3, 
        30.3, 
        31.3, 
        32.3, 
        33.3, 
        34.3, 
        35.3, 
        36.3, 
...
```

[Example](https://mongoplayground.net/p/HWZDgXkUd-a)

Answer (score 1):

Try this query and check if it is the behaviour you expect (example [here](https://mongoplayground.net/p/o_RpweTFz5-))

Note that I've change dates for number to read easier.

```js
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    "$match": {
      "feedId": 2
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "events": {
        "$objectToArray": "$events"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$events"
  },
  {
    "$sort": {
      "events.v.t": 1
    }
  },
  {
    "$group": {
      "_id": "$_id",
      "events": {
        "$push": "$events"
      }
    }
  },
  {
    "$addFields": {
      "count": "$events.v.a.Amount"
    }
  },
  {
    "$project": {
      "count": 1,
      "_id": 0
    }
  }
])
```

First `$match` the `feedId` field, then is necessary use `$objectToArray` since your schema is compound by key-values objects.
Then `$unwind` to can do the `$sort` and regroup again.
After that I've added a new field `count` that contains the total amount and I've used `$project` to shor only this field.

Comment: I ran the above and it didn't quite produce the results, but it got me close.  This query returned
```
/* 1 */
{
    "count" : [ 
        147.3, 
        148.3, 
        149.3, 
        150.3, 
        151.3, 
        152.3
    ]
}

/* 2 */
{
    "count" : [ 
        27.3, 
        28.3, 
        29.3, 
        30.3, 
        31.3, 
        32.3, 
        33.3, 
        34.3, 
        35.3, 
        36.3, 
        37.3, 
        38.3
    ]
} ...
```. 
The Amounts were not sorted properly (all the amounts should ascend). I'll post the answer separately below.